# How do I write the code to deduct one hit point?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Working on a Basketball Shooter on a unit. I am doing the part that is responsible for subtracting the cells of life. The part of the code that is responsible for adding points is triggered when you touch the "Bonus" component and adds points, but the next part of the code that is responsible for reducing health does not work. By design, this should happen after the ball does not hit the "Bonus" object and comes into contact with the "Terraine" object. How to write a code so that if there is no touch with the "Bonus" object and then there is a touch with the "Terraine" object, one life point is subtracted?

```
public GameObject hp3;
public GameObject hp2;
public GameObject hp1;

int score = 0;
int best = 0;

void Awake()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    col = GetComponent<Collider>();

    //instance = this;
}

private void Start()
{
    best = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("best", 0);

    scoreText.text = "Score: " + score.ToString();
    bestScoreText.text = "Best: " + best.ToString();
}

public void Push(Vector2 force)
{
    rb.AddForce(force, ForceMode.Impulse);
}

public void ActivateRb()
{
    rb.isKinematic = false;
}

public void DesactivateRb()
{
    rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
    //rb.angularVelocity = 0f;
    rb.isKinematic = true;
}

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.name == "Terraine")
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-4f, 8f), Random.Range(2f, 7f), -0.2f);
        DesactivateRb();
    }
}

public void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.name == "Bonus")
    {
        score += 2;
        scoreText.text = "Score: " + score.ToString();
        if (best < score)
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("best", score);
    }

    if (other.gameObject.name != "Bonus")
    {
        health = health - 1;
    }
}

void Update()
{
    if (health == 3)
    {
        hp3.SetActive(true);
        hp2.SetActive(false);
        hp1.SetActive(false);
    }
    if (health == 2)
    {
        hp3.SetActive(false);
        hp2.SetActive(true);
        hp1.SetActive(false);
    }
    if (health == 1)
    {
        hp3.SetActive(false);
        hp2.SetActive(false);
        hp1.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would work with states. First you are in the state e.g. `WaitingForBonus` -> if you hit bonus -> `HaveHitBonus` -> collide with `Terrain` -> no problem. If you didn't hit bonus so state is still `WaitingForBonus` -> collide with Terrain -> ouch! After hitting terrain always go back to `WaitingForBonus`

Answer (score 0):

Don't know c#, but would something as simple as this work?
Hard to know without the logic.

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.name == "Terraine")
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-4f, 8f), Random.Range(2f, 7f), -0.2f);
        DesactivateRb();
        if (flag != 1)
        {
        health = health - 1;
        }
        else
        {
        flag = 0;    //reset flag if 1
        }
    }
}

public void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.name == "Bonus")
    {
        score += 2;
        flag = 1;
        scoreText.text = "Score: " + score.ToString();
        if (best < score)
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("best", score);
    }

}
```